# How to verify stored value to expected value in selenium ide

Tags: wordpress, selenium-ide

I am new to selenium IDE. I have evaluated some value and stored it in a variable. Now i have store another value which i get from UI element. What i wanted is to check if both value is same or not.

For that i have used below code

```
  command:- store text
  Target:- css=li:nth-child(7) > .value
  Value:- res

  command:- echo
  Target:- ${res}  // output  echo: 1
 
  command:- execute script
  Target:- return ${totalTicket} - ${usedTicket}
  Value:- result

  command:- echo
  Target:- ${result}  // output echo: 1
```

Now i wanted to check if result equal res for that i have used below code.

```
  command:- assert
  Target:- ${result}
  Value:- ${res}
```

I am getting error
`assert on ${result} with value ${res} Failed: 18:05:26 Actual value 'undefined' did not match '1'`

Answer (score 0):

In Target we need to pass variable name at the time of assert not the value of it.

```
 command:- assert
 Target:- result
 Value:- ${res}
```